# UIViewRepresentable updateUIView() strange behaviour when using .sheet()

Tags: swift, swiftui, uiviewrepresentable

I just found some strange behaviour of SwiftUI's UIViewRepresentable. I'm not sure if this is a bug, or my mistake in understanding SwiftUI.
I've made small reproduction to show the problem.

I created UIViewRepresentable for MKMapView:

```swift
import SwiftUI
import MapKit

struct UIMap: UIViewRepresentable {
  
  func makeUIView(context: Context) -> MKMapView {
    let map = MKMapView(frame: .zero)
    map.delegate = context.coordinator
    return map
  }
  
  func updateUIView(_ map: MKMapView, context: Context) {
    print("Change!")
  }
  
  func makeCoordinator() -> UIMapCoordinator {
    return UIMapCoordinator(self)
  }
  
  class UIMapCoordinator: NSObject, MKMapViewDelegate {
    var parent: UIMap
    
    init(_ parent: UIMap) {
      self.parent = parent
    }
  }
}
```

Then I create really small wrapper for this representable:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct MapWrapper: View {
  var body: some View {
    UIMap()
  }
}
```

Finally I'm using it in ContentView:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
  @State private var showSheet = false
  @State private var showButton = true
  
  var body: some View {
    ZStack(alignment: .bottom){
      MapWrapper()
      HStack{
        if showButton {
          Button(action: { showSheet = true }){
            Text("Show Sheet")
          }
          .foregroundColor(.yellow)
        }
        Spacer()
        Button(action: { showButton = !showButton }){
          Text("Toggle Button")
        }
        .foregroundColor(.yellow)
      }
    }
    .sheet(isPresented: $showSheet) {
      Text("Sheet content")
    }
  }
}
```

I have two clickable elements in ContentView - one for opening a sheet, and another for hiding button (just to see state change). Opening sheet (changing `showSheet` to `true`) causes `updateUIView` being called ("Change!" is printed in debug console), while changing `showButton` doesn't do that. It looks like opening sheet changes state of `MapWrapper`(?). Is this behaviour correct?

Comment: Only Apple can answer on this question, if it is called then SwiftUI internals decided that it should be called, so I'd recommend to accept the situation as-it-is.

Comment: Thanks @Asperi, is there option that it's not intended behaviour aka should it be reported to Apple?

Comment: @MaksymilianTomczyk have you ever found a decent solution to this? Asking for a friend ;)